# Bash script find if file is created less then X time ago

Tags: bash

I want to have a bash script witch tells me **if the file is created less than a 1h ago**.

Any suggestion how I can achieve that?

Comment: Most Unix filesystems don't store creation time. They store modification time, access time, and inode change time. Which of these do you really want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use find command with -mmin option.

```
if [ `find path/to/file -mmin -60 | wc -c` -gt 0 ]; then
    #found
fi
```

Comment: mtime is usually the proxy for creation time, not ctime.

Comment: This will not work well ... in most situations.  If there is only one name output by `find` (and it contains no white space), this will work.  But not if there is more than one name, or if the output of find looks like "3 -lt 1" .  If you want to check that a program produces output, it is better to do something else.  eg `if find ... | grep -q .; then ...`

Comment: You can use the bash built-in `[ -s path/to/file ]` to replace the pipe and subshell for `wc -c`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin sorry I can't catch it, the problem is not to check whether the file exists.

Comment: `-s` checks whether the file is non-empty.